# Binary Search Tree Creating Stack- overlfow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, binary-search-tree

I am getting an stack overflow when the program tries to add a number. It seems to be accessing a nonexistent binary search tree. Here is the error code:
Unhandled exception at 0x01084DD9 in CIS 350 question 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD5.
Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>  // for permutations
using namespace std;

struct BST
{
    BST* left;
    BST* right;
    int d;

    BST(int data)
    {
        d = data;
        BST* left;
        BST* right;
        cout << d << endl;
    }
    void add(int data)
    {
        cout << d << "    |   " << data << endl;
        if (d < data){
            if (right == NULL){
                right = new BST(data);
            }
            else{
                right->add(data);
            }
        }
        else{
            if (left == NULL){
                left = new BST(data);
            }
            else{
                left->add(data);
            }
        }
     }
   }
int main()
{
    BST* test1 = new BST(12);
    test1->add(14);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `left` and `right` are not initialized (with `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by AlexD in comments, the segmentation fault arises from the fact that `struct BST` members `left` and `right` are not initialized to `NULL`.

Note that this is hinted by the error which indicates "Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD5". Location 0xCDCDCDCD, when using Microsoft C++ runtime library is a magic number which marks uninitialized memory.

Location 0xCDCDCDD5 (8 byte offset from 0xCDCDCDCD) arises as the code `left->add(data)` attempts to write in member `left->d` (8 byte offset from the location pointed to by `left`).